# Jade - How to create table with checkbox

Tags: gulp, pug

How to create this code in jade template?

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
  <th>User</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>haacki47</td>
</tr>
```

I use compiler gulp-jade 
I try to use

```
each val in ["#","<input type='checkbox'>","User"]
```

But i getting error :=(

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Can not use "<input type='checkbox'>" inside each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multidimensional array should solve your problem ? 
Also instead of passing a HTML inside the data, it is better to handle it in Jade

```
- var datas = [
-   {
-     index: "#",
-     input: "checkbox",
-     name: "user"
-   },
-   {
-     index: "1",
-     input: "checkbox",
-     name: "haacki47"
-   }
- ];

table
  each data in datas
    tr
      td=data.index
      td
        case data.input
          when "checkbox"
            input(type="checkbox")
      td=data.name
```

Codepen : http://codepen.io/Pototo/pen/mVeRwm

Comment: Why are there dashes in front of every line of `datas`?

Comment: To write inline javascript

Comment: Can you point me at a reference that explains what you mean by that? Thank you.

Comment: Basically, inside the jade file, you can write javascript. [See here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/)